# Setting WPF nested control properties from the parent control

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF window, with multiple ListBox controls on it, all sharing the same style that I've simplified here:

```
   <Style x:Key="listBox" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=text}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="id:" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="_idTextBlock" Text="{Binding Path=id}" />
                            <Button Name="btnGet" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=id}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And here is an example of one of the ListBox controls using that style:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbCampaigns" Button.Click="lbCampaigns_Click" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource listBox}" />
```

*How can I set the Content of the Button control (btnGet) from within the parent ListBox?*

I know what text I want the button to display at design time for each ListBox on the Window. (i.e. I don't need to bind it to the ListBox ItemsSource). I see that I can define the child control's events (see the Button.Click definition), but it doesn't appear that I can set the child control's properties in the same manner.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your setting of `Button.Click` isn't assigning the event handler to the Button. It's assigning it to the `ListBox`. It works because of WPF's routed event system.

If you want the `Button` to take on a value set at the level of the `ListBox`, one option in this case is to use a `Binding` with a `RelativeSource`:

```
<Button Content="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"/>
```

In this case I've just hijacked the `Tag` property, which you can specify as follows:

```
<ListBox Tag="This is the button's content" .../>
```

Another option is to use an inherited attached property. For example:

```
<Button Content="{Binding local:MyClass.MyAttachedProperty}"/>
```

And then:

```
<ListBox local:MyClass.MyAttachedProperty="This is the button's content"/>
```

Finally, if you were templating the `ListBox` itself, you can "reach out" and bind to a property of the control you're templating using a `TemplateBinding`:

```
<Button Content="{TemplateBinding Tag}"/>
```

Of course, this technique is generally used with properties specifically declared on the templated control. For example, you could subclass `ListBox` and add your own `ButtonContent` property. Then, in your template you could reach out and bind to that property from the `Button`.

Comment: Hi Kent, thanks for your help. Is there a typo in your FindAncestor code snippet?
When I copy paste it into my button content property, I get a "AncestorType must be specified for RelativeSource in FindAncestor mode." error.
I'll keep looking, but thought I'd mention it, in case you can help more.:)

Comment: bah, looks like a VisualStudio error. I did a solution rebuild, and the error went away! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, that's a common error when pasting a binding with a relativesource. I have it all the time.

Comment: @Scott: you're welcome. I just did some edits to my post to make it a little clearer and comprehensive.